Parallel sf join in R
I have a large point (N) to polygon (M) join I need to do. The dimensions are 826k abd 308k respectively. Given the size, and that it's an embarrassingly parallel problem, I'm attempting to do this in parallel using my usual go to parallel packages. I've tried using a parallel for loop (foreach + doParallel), parlapply (using parallel) and future_lapply (using future.apply).
My approach is to have an outer sequential loop over batches of points N, and then within each loop do the spatial join of the batch of points to all polygons M, in parallel. The purpose of the outer loop is to be able to better monitor progress, as well as export batches of results to csv. Below is a sample of the code using the future package, the general structure is the same whether using future, parlapply or foreach+dopar.
For clarity
unique_latlong_sf  is the point, of size N, sf object
region_polygons is the polygon, of size M, sf object
library(sf)
library(future.apply)
library(dplyr)

# import data ...

# Set number of cores
n_cores <- 36

# Set up parallel processing with the desired number of workers
plan(multisession, workers = n_cores)

# Split the polygons into chunks of 1000 polygons each
polygons_per_chunk <- 1000
polygon_chunks <- split(region_polygons, cut(seq(nrow(region_polygons)), ceiling(nrow(region_polygons) / polygons_per_chunk), labels = FALSE))

# Loop over each batch
for (batch_number in 1:total_batches) {
  # Print start message
  cat(sprintf("Processing batch %d of %d\n", batch_number, total_batches))
  
  # Start the timer for the batch
  start_time_batch <- Sys.time()
  
  # Subset unique_latlong_sf for the current batch
  unique_latlong_sf_subset <- unique_latlong_sf[((batch_number - 1) * batch_size + 1):min(batch_number * batch_size, nrow(unique_latlong_sf)), ]
  
  # Apply the spatial join function to each chunk in parallel
  results_list <- future_lapply(polygon_chunks, spatial_join_merge, unique_latlong_sf = unique_latlong_sf_subset, future.seed = TRUE)
  
  # Combine the results for the current batch
  polygons_combined_batch <- do.call(rbind, results_list)

  # Store the combined results for this batch
  results_list_all_batches[[batch_number]] <- polygons_combined_batch
}

In all cases of parallel implementation no error codes are thrown, all workers initiate and I can see their ram usage increase to the expected level in task manager. However the cpu usage stays very low, almost all workers in taskmanager have no cpu usage suggesting that the job isn't being carried out as expected in parallel, though it is running through, presumably just like it would sequentially.
Do you have any suggestions?
Below I have included the definition of the spatial_join_merge function above.
spatial_join_merge <- function(polygon_chunk, unique_latlong_sf_subset) {
  joined_data <- st_join(polygon_chunk, unique_latlong_sf_subset, join = st_contains)
  return(joined_data)
}


Where does spatial_join_merge come from?

Thanks for pointing that out. Amended

Your code also doesn't compute total_batches for the loop, or batch_size inside the loop. Can't tell if this is the problem, maybe you've got them set wrongly. Try putting all the operational code in a function(pts, polys, polys_per_chunk) for testing.

Ah that's just trying to be parsimonious with the code I've copied over, they're both defined appropriately. Will try your suggestion. Thanks
